# Restriction of a linear algebra to an affine subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's assume $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces and, $F:W\longrightarrow V$ is a one-to-one affine map i.e, $F(W)$ is an affine subspace of $V$. Also, let $T:V\longrightarrow V$ is a linear map. Define $\hat{T}:F(W)\longrightarrow F(W)$ such that for all $x\in W$, $\hat{T}(F(x))=P_{F(W)} (F(x))$, Where $P_{F(W)}(F(x))$ is projection of $F(x)$ into the affine subspace $F(W)$.

Does this definition seems logical?

Comment: You say $W$ is a vector space, but then you say $W$ is an affine subspace of $V$. How does that work? What do you mean by affine subpace?

Comment: Yes, this defines a function, and the definition makes sense.

Comment: @GerryMyerson OP means that $F(W)$ is an affine subspace of $V$.  Since $F$ is an affine isomorphism of $W$ with $F(W)$, it's kind of okay to conflate the two spaces.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How do you define an affine subspace of a vector space? A vector space isn't an affine space, even though in principle you could make it onto one by considering its action on itself...

Comment: @A.P. an affine subspace of a vector space is a subset of vectors that is closed under affine combinations.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: @A.P. I assume he means an affine space in [this sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_subspace)

Comment: @A.P. No; affine combinations allow negative coefficients.  A space is an affine subspace of $V$ iff it is the solution set to $Tx = b$ for some linear $T:V \to W$ and $b \in W$

Comment: Your definition doesn't make use of $T$ at all. Do you actually mean $\hat{T}(F(x))=P_{F(W)} (T(F(x)))$? Otherwise $P_{F(W)} (F(x)) = F(x)$ means that $\hat{T}$ would be the identity on $F(W)$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $V$ is equipped with an inner product and $P_{F(W)}$ refers to *orthogonal* (affine) projection to $F(W)$, then yes, $\hat{T}:F(W) \to F(W)$ is well-defined.

In the absence of an inner product on $V$ or some fixed choice of projection $P:V \to F(W) \subset V$, "the definition is not logical".